# Returning static page by concrete path with Nginx

Tags: web, nginx

It is very easy, but I have not found a direct answer to this simple question

I have link like

> mysite/api/location/login

and i need to return static page

> login.html

which lies in directory

> root /data/www/

```
location =/api/location/login {
root /data/www/;
 how to return static page here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use "root" here, you'll get /data/www/api/location/login as a result. Use "alias" instead

```
location = /api/location/login {
    alias /data/www/;
    index login.html;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index